# Which is grammatically correct?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Two solid waste drawers, with containers that accommodate biohazard bags, are accessed **at** the front of the instrument. or..

Two solid waste drawers, with containers that accommodate biohazard bags, are accessed **from** the front of the instrument.

Comment: 'From' may have the broadened meaning 'via' when used in 'get at via', and I can't see much wrong with 'at' here either.

Comment: 'At' means you pull the drawer directly at the front. 'From' means there may be extra steps, but you start from the front (perhaps you open a cabinet door or slide.)

Comment: I agree with both comments above, but I whereas think "grammatically correct" is an inappropriate concept here, I do think the the first version would be stylistically improved by simply discarding the word ***accessed***. And *semantically*, the second looks at least questionable (it just doesn't seem likely that such *drawers* would somehow be so far inside the instrument that we'd talk about getting at them *through* the front; they're just *there*).

Comment: What does instrument mean?  Musical?

Comment: I'd suggest that the word that's not quite right is 'accessed'. To my ear it sounds like you mean 'the drawers are **located** at the front . . .'
Alternatively 'accessed' would be more appropriate in something like 'the biohazard bags are accessed via the removable panel at the front of the instrument'

Answer (score 0):

*at the front of the instrument* is correct (if I read this sentence correctly to mean that the solid waste drawers are physically located where the front of the instrument is and not, perhaps, down some secret passage which is found at the front of the instrument or via controls located on the instrument panel, which controls allow one to open the drawers in some other location like the side wall).

*access* means *to make contact with or gain access to*

*at* means *presence or location*

*from* means *a starting point*

All definitions from dictionary.com

So if you say *accessed at* you mean to *location to gain access to* and if you say *accessed from* you mean *starting point to gain access to*

Think about it this way.  I typically access my work computer *at* my desk *at* my work; however, I also have the ability to access my work computer *from* my home computer *from* my home or any other remote location with Internet access.

I will meet you *at* the party but I will leave for the party *from* my house.